# AndEngine Vector2 class

Tags: android, andengine

I want to ask a basic question just to make sure. When we use Vector2 class for representing some vector in andengine like when we use in joint creation as:

```
jointDef.localAnchorA.set(new Vector2(1, 1));
```

Do the values passed i.e. 1, 1 represent 1 meter each?

A little more explanation. Suppose I have created two bodies as:

```
Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(10, 10, 100, 100, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        Body body1 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, rect1, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);

        Rectangle rect2 = new Rectangle(110, 110, 50, 50, vertexBufferObjectManager);
        Body body2 = PhysicsFactory.createBoxBody(mPhysicsWorld, rect2, BodyType.DynamicBody, FIXTURE_DEF);
```

And want to create a revolute joint at the position shown in the image below:

[image]

So what values for vectors localAnchorpointA and localAnchorPointB should I set to place the upper right corner of red rectangle touching the center of white rectangle? Like:

```
jointDef.localAnchorA.set(new Vector2(?, ?));
    jointDef.localAnchorB.set(new Vector2(?, ?));
```

This would be very helpful in understanding the usage of vector2 class.

Answer (score 2):

You need to understand what does a Vector2 class represent and stands for in game development. It basically encapsulates the provided coordinates in the 2D space. Taking it a step further, it has numerous applications for which it can be used, from distance calculations to other basic algebraic calculations. [**Stiegart Blog**](http://steigert.blogspot.com/2012/05/11-libgdx-tutorial-vectors.html) will give you a much clear idea about Vector2 in android. Hope it clarifies the confusion and misunderstanding.

Answer (score 0):

The Vector2 has no associated units, you decide what the coordinates space looks like on the screen, when you render it (by choosing an appropriate camera). For angels You have to use radians.

But as I can see, You are passing it to the Box2D physics engine. It is recommanded to use units close to m/kg/s. Making your character 2m high would be a good choice. Making your spaceship Enterprise 10km across in Your asteroids game would be too much.

More information can be found in this post: http://box2d.org/2011/12/pixels/ .